# is there a hack for disabling popup menu items in 3rd party application, e.g. Visual Studio?

Tags: windows, visual-studio

the motivation for this question is my unhappiness with Visual Studio gui, but it might have wider implications.

Suppose I right click on file name tab for my current document. I will be presented with a popup menu with useful options that I might use, like close this document, and some potentially downright harmful notions, like close all documents but this. If I accidentally click the wrong one, I will have to undo the damage and it will be annoying.

Well, so I understand that I cannot expect Microsoft (not to mention smaller companies) to add customization for each and every one of menu items. But, perhaps there is a Windows hack that could allow me to disable such menu items and other elements of the user interface? Let's say the "close everything but this" could be detected by its distinct name, so if the underlying component is somehow accessible for hacking, perhaps it could be made to be always disabled when displaying such text, unless the user jumps through hoops to undo the restriction.

So how do these things work? To what extent can we mess with the 3rd party Windows apps user interface? What can and cannot be done?

Comment: "and some potentially downright harmful notions, like close all documents but this" - why would you think this harmful? It causes no damage.

Comment: You can look to see if there is an XML or other data file that contains the presentation logic for the context menu(s), and edit that file to omit your option. It may also be a properties or other type of file. Not sure if it's possible directly with VS, though.

Answer (score 2):

> Well, so I understand that I cannot
>   expect Microsoft (not to mention
>   smaller companies) to add
>   customization for each and every one
>   of menu items

Well, they did.  They as in Microsoft anyway, this is otherwise common in well designed UIs like the one in Visual Studio.  You use Tools + Customize, Commands tab, Context menu radio button, "Other Context Menus | Easy MDI Document Window".  Remove/add what you dis/like.

Click around a bit, see what you can do.  Don't fear the menu.

If the capability is not present, it may be possible to hack the menu if it is stored as a native resource.  File + Open + File, select the .exe and browse the Menu nodes.  It is not that common to use native menus anymore these days.  Plenty of opportunity for trouble as well.  Hacking the program with a hook set by SetWindowsHookEx() is another long distance shot.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio (you haven't said which version) does have an extensibility SDK and the ability to load add-ins and extensions, which may let you do that.

Answer (score 0):

I am giving you code written by me to disable any Context Menu of a MDI Parent from a MDI Child form.
It is a crazy piece of code, but it works fine.

This is the Child form:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MDI.MDIParent1.ActiveForm.MainMenuStrip.Items[0].ToolTipText = "Disable";
}
```

This is the MID Parent code:

The Timer interval is 1000 milliseconds and it is enabled on  `MDIParent1_Load`.
`fileMenu` is a Menu Strip in the MDI parent and
`aboutToolStripMenuItem` is the Context Menu in the MDI parent.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (fileMenu.ToolTipText == "Disable")
    {
        aboutToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```